# Navigating to another page in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, hyperlink, navigation

Hi i have such a problem. I have a list that contains a title and a picture, which I display on the main page of the application. When you click on the picture, another page should open corresponding to this element, but the same first page always opens. I tried to create separate files for each page, but I cannot link a separate page to a separate button. Thanks in advance.

**home.dart:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_icons/flutter_icons.dart';
import 'package:furniture_app/util/data.dart';
//import 'package:furniture_app/widgets/badge.dart';
import 'package:furniture_app/widgets/product_item.dart';
import 'package:furniture_app/widgets/room_item.dart';
import 'package:furniture_app/widgets/room_item2.dart';
import 'package:furniture_app/widgets/room_item3.dart';
//import 'package:furniture_app/widgets/search_card.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          Center(
          ),
          SizedBox(width: 20.0),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0),
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
            child: Text(
              "Поиск низких цен \nна товары  и услуги",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 35.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),

          SizedBox(height: 30.0),
          buildRoomList(),
          SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          buildTitleRow(),
          buildProductList(),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  buildRoomList() {
    return Container(
      height: 275,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: furnitures.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          Map furniture = furnitures[index];
          return RoomItem(
            furniture: furniture,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  buildTitleRow() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          "Примеры использования",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 23,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  buildProductList() {
    return Container(
      height: 140.0,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: furnitures.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          Map furniture2 = furnitures2[index];

          return ProductItem(
            furniture: furniture2,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**main_screen.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_icons/flutter_icons.dart';
import 'package:furniture_app/screens/home.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {
  PageController _pageController;
  int _page = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        controller: _pageController,
        onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
        children: List.generate(4, (index) => Home()),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          canvasColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          primaryColor: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
          textTheme: Theme.of(context).textTheme.copyWith(
                caption: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500]),
              ),
        ),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Feather.home,
              ),
              title: Container(height: 0.0),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Feather.heart,
              ),
              title: Container(height: 0.0),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Feather.user,
              ),
              title: Container(height: 0.0),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Feather.grid,
              ),
              title: Container(height: 0.0),
            ),
          ],
          onTap: navigationTapped,
          currentIndex: _page,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void navigationTapped(int page) {
    _pageController.jumpToPage(page);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 2);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _pageController.dispose();
  }

  void onPageChanged(int page) {
    setState(() {
      this._page = page;
    });
  }
}
```

**details.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_icons/flutter_icons.dart';
import 'package:furniture_app/util/data.dart';
//import 'package:furniture_app/widgets/badge.dart';
import 'package:furniture_app/widgets/product_item.dart';

class Details extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DetailsState createState() => _DetailsState();
}

class _DetailsState extends State<Details> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              buildImage(),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              Text(
                "${furnitures[0]["name"]}",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 32.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              Text(
                "\$550.00",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 27.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 30.0),
              Text(
                "Description",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              Text(
                "Sed porttitor lectus nibh. Cras ultricies ligula "
                "sed magna dictum porta. Praesent sapien massa, "
                "convallis a pellentesque nec, egestas non nisi. "
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing "
                "elit. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. "
                "Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, "
                "porttitor at sem.",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 15.0,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              Text(
                "Photos",
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              buildProductList(),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            ],
          ),
          buildFloatingButton(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  buildProductList() {
    return Container(
      height: 100.0,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: furnitures.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          Map furniture = furnitures.reversed.toList()[index];

          return ProductItem(
            furniture: furniture,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  buildFloatingButton() {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
        child: Container(
          height: 60.0,
          width: 60.0,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.orange[200],
                offset: Offset(0.0, 10.0),
                blurRadius: 10,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Icon(
              Feather.plus,
              color: Colors.white,
              size: 25.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  buildImage() {
    return Container(
      height: 240.0,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            child: Image.asset(
              "${furnitures[0]["img"]}",
              height: 240.0,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**product_item.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../screens/details.dart';

class ProductItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map furniture;

  ProductItem({this.furniture});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Details();
              },
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 140,
          width: 140,
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
            child: Image.asset(
              "${furniture["img"]}",
              height: 140,
              width: 140,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**room_item.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:furniture_app/screens/details2.dart';
import 'package:furniture_app/screens/details3.dart';
import 'package:furniture_app/util/data.dart';

import '../screens/details.dart';

class RoomItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Map furniture;

  RoomItem({this.furniture});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Details();
              },
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 275,
          width: 280,
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                furniture['name'],
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 20,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                child: Image.asset(
                  "${furniture["img"]}",
                  height: 240,
                  width: 280,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**data.dart**

```
List furnitures = [
  {
    "name": "Оставить заявку",
    "img": "assets/1.png",
  },
  {
    "name": "О сервисе",
    "img": "assets/2.png",
  },
  {
    "name": "Руководителям",
    "img": "assets/3.png",
  },
];

List furnitures2 = [
  {
    "name": "Оставить заявку",
    "img": "assets/1.jpeg",
  },
  {
    "name": "О сервисе",
    "img": "assets/2.jpeg",
  },
  {
    "name": "Руководителям",
    "img": "assets/3.jpeg",
  },
];
```

Answer (score 0):

The below example creates a list of furniture from a `List` when clicked a new product page is opened with the name and image URL.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:stackoverflow/products.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 List furniture =  [
 {
 "name": "Оставить заявку",
 "img": "assets/1.png",
 },
 {
 "name": "О сервисе",
 "img": "assets/1.png",
 },
 {
 "name": "Руководителям",
 "img": "assets/1.png",
 },
 ];


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Container(child: ListView(
        children: furniture.map((furniture){
          return ListTile(title: Text(furniture['name']),leading: Image.asset(furniture['img']),onTap: (){
            Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Products(furniture: furniture,),));
          },);
        }).toList(),
      ),)
    );
  }
}
```

**Products.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Products extends StatefulWidget {
  dynamic furniture;
  Products({this.furniture});
  @override
  _ProductsState createState() => _ProductsState();
}

class _ProductsState extends State<Products> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.furniture['name']),),
      body: Container(child: Column(
        children: [
          Image.asset(widget.furniture['img']),
        ],
      ),),
    );
  }
}
```

**Image's**

[image]

[image]

Note: I have only used one image in the assets so I assigned the image path as ***1.png*** for all list item make sure to change the image path